# convert py file for RPIO to RPi.GPIO

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, pwm, rpio

According to Joan's instruction.

First, 
git clone https://github.com/metachris/RPIO.git

cd RPIO

sudo python setup.py install

sudo python3 setup.py install

and

sudo python3 jjy.py

[image: error message]

---

I made a jjy time server using raspberry pi 3.

Reference site is https://github.com/snt/rpi_jjy_server .

I downloaded jjy.py file from reference site.

However, jjy.py file couldn't be executed because raspberry pi 3 used RPi.GPIO instead of RPIO. jjy.py used RPIO as PWM module.

So I want to convert RPIO version to RPi.GPIO version. Can you help me?

jjy.py contents is as below.

```py
import datetime

import time

import sched

import sys

from RPIO import PWM as pwm

JJY_FORMAT="M{0:03b}0{1:04b}M00{2:02b}0{3:04b}M00{4:02b}0{5:04b}M{6:04b}00{10}{11}0M0{7:04b}{8:04b}M{9:03b}000000M"

IO_PIN=4 # BCM4 = board 7

def pwm_setup():

pwm.set_loglevel(pwm.LOG_LEVEL_ERRORS)

pwm.setup(5)

pwm.init_channel(0, 5000)

# M 200 [ms]

# 1 500 [ms]

# 0 800 [ms]

SIGNAL_LENGTHS = {'M': 0.2, '1': 0.5, '0': 0.8}

DEBUG=False

def send_signal(signal):

for x in range(1,1000,5): 

pwm.add_channel_pulse(0, IO_PIN, x ,3)

time.sleep(SIGNAL_LENGTHS[signal])

pwm.clear_channel_gpio(0, IO_PIN)

if DEBUG:

sys.stdout.write(signal)

sys.stdout.flush()

def schedule_next (scheduler):

a = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)

next0sec = time.mktime(datetime.datetime(a.year, a.month, a.day, a.hour, a.minute, 0, 0).timetuple())

ts = a.strftime('%M%H%j%y%w,%H,%M').split(',')

data = [int(x) for x in ts[0]]

parities = ["".join(["{:b}".format(int(x)) for x in ps]).count('1') % 2 for ps in ts[1:]]

signals = JJY_FORMAT.format(*(data + parities))

for i, signal in enumerate(signals):

scheduler.enterabs(next0sec + i, 1, send_signal, (signal,))

scheduler.enterabs(next0sec, 1, schedule_next, (scheduler,))

print datetime.datetime.now()

if __name__ == '__main__':

pwm_setup()

scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

schedule_next(scheduler)

scheduler.run()

print "schedule empty"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RPIO.GPIO uses hardware timed PWM (possibly the reason you used it in the first place).

RPi.GPIO only supports software timed PWM, which may or may not be okay for what you want to do.

It might be simpler just to update RPIO.GPIO which you can do **if you follow** the following instructions.  There will be other methods, these are the ones I used.

The standard release of RPIO does not support the Pi Zero, Pi2, or Pi3.

You will need to build RPIO from the github of RPIO version 2.

See https://github.com/metachris/RPIO/tree/v2

Go to **that github** choose Clone or download and **select Download ZIP**.

Then do the following on the Pi where you saved the ZIP.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev
unzip RPIO-2.zip
cd RPIO-2/
sudo python setup.py install
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your method. but I didn't make it. SystemError: This module can only be run on a raspberry pi! This is error message. Please help me...

Comment: I will only try to help if you edit your question and include a log of each command you gave to upgrade to V2 and the corresponding system response.  Perhaps delete any ZIP you downloaded and start again.

Comment: I edited my question. Tell me about information you need...please..

Comment: You have not provided the information I asked for.

Comment: The problem is resolved. I tried to download zip file instead of clone. and carried out your instruction again. Thank you so much Joan.....